# Passar id de uma empresa de activity para outra e usar em um conexao com banco de dados

Tags: android, android-activity, intent

Estou passando um id de um usuário através de de um intent e pretendo usar esse id na segunda activity. Ate acredito estar correto deem uma olhada no código:

Tenho que passar dessa activity para outra o id do usuario:

```
ltsunidades = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ltsunidades);

            final ArrayAdapter<Tab_UC> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tab_UC>
                    (Selecionar_Unidade.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista);
            ltsunidades.setAdapter(adapter);

            //selecionando unidade
            ltsunidades.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View viw, int posicao, long id) {
                    id = adapter.getItemIdAtPosition(posicao);
                    Intent it = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Empresa.class);
                    it.putExtra("id", id);
                    startActivity(it);
                }
            });

        }// end post execute
    }// end async task
```

recebendo o id na segunda activity

```
Intent it = getIntent();               //aqui eu recebo o id da outra activity 
        id = it.getIntExtra("id",0);  // preciso saber ser esta certo?


                                   // e preciso usar esse "id " no lugar dessa 
                                     Preferencia e eu não sei como usar
        url = url.replace("par1", Preferencia.getCodEmpresa(this));
        Log.i("URL", "" + url);
    }
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use putExtra, na intent que chama a próxima activity faça:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(...);
    i.putExtra("Id", "123");
```

Na activity chamada faça:

```
   Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    Log.i("id", b.getString("Id", null));
```

Um outro exemplo pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data)